# How to align an inline <p> at the center of the line with greater width in HTML?

Tags: html, css

I have this code for showing the information about an user:

```css
.creator-name {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

.face {
    height: 32px;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 16px;
}

.creator {
    float: right;
    border: 4px solid #ddd;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 0 16px 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="creator">
    <img class="face" src="https://picsum.photos/400">
    <p class="creator-name">username</p>
</div>
```

But the username isn't aligned properly. I want to change the CSS somehow to make the username text to be aligned at the center of the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `flexbox` to do that. Check the below snippet.

If you are planning to align it vertically middle, use the `align-items` property of `flexbox`

```css
.creator-name {
    margin: 0;
    display: inline;
}

.face {
    height: 32px;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 16px;
}

.creator {
    float: right;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    border: 4px solid #ddd;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 0 16px 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="creator">
    <img class="face" src="https://picsum.photos/400">
    <p class="creator-name">username</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I added to the creator div `display:flex` and `align-items: center`

```css
.creator-name {
    margin: 0;
    margin-left: 5px;
    display: inline;
}

.face {
    height: 32px;
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 16px;
}

.creator {
    float: right;
    border: 4px solid #ddd;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 0 16px 0 16px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="creator">
    <img class="face" src="https://picsum.photos/400">
    <p class="creator-name">username</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px; line-height: 1.5; display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
 
.face {
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 16px;
}

.creator {
    float: right;
    display: flex;
    width: 105px;   
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    border: 4px solid #ddd;
    padding: 16px;
    border-radius: 0 16px 0 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="creator">
    <img class="face" src="https://picsum.photos/400">
    <p class="creator-name">username</p>
</div>
```